# Remove the mysql output from the Cakephp 2.5 default layout

Tags: cakephp-2.5

Is there anyway to remove the mysql output from the cakephp default layout without the need to change the complete default layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of default.ctp there is a line

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

change it to

```
<?php //echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```